# How to avoid Jest test conflicts with parallel tests and `mongodb-memory-server`

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

I'm using `mongodb-memory-server` to test my Node/Mongoose/Express project. The tests were getting a little slow and I realized I was starting up `mongodb-memory-server` in every test file. So, I switched to having a `globalSetup` and a `globalTeardown` and adding something like this in `setupFilesAfterEnv`.

```
afterEach(async () => {
  const collections = mongoose.connection.collections;

  for (const key in collections) {
    const collection = collections[key];
    await collection.deleteMany({});
  }
});
```

It made the tests substantially faster! However when the tests are run in parallel there are sporadic failures. In particular, I'll get errors of the shape "email address already in use" because my `register.test.ts` tests creates a user that conflict with my `login.test.ts` tests. (they'll both create users with the same email address)

When I add `--runInBand` this doesn't happen since the tests are executed sequentially. I'm curious how things like this *should* bar handled:

1. Should I be creating common fixtures to be used across tests in a `beforeAll`?
2. Should I be creating factories to avoid conflicts like this?
3. Should core functionality like `login` and `register` not be tested in parallel?
4. Is it better to create new `mongodb-memory-server` for each test file, even if it is slow?
5. any more ideas welcomed :)

Comment: We run one server and abandon parallelism - but I think the "right" answer is up to the scope/scale of your project. You might also want to consider that unit tests that don't hit mongo could run separately and be in parallel - many people mock the data access layer for their parallel tests, then test the data access layer more in isolation, but there are obviously tradeoffs with that approach.

Comment: Running into this exact thing. What did you end up doing?